# Filling Many2many field (odoo 8)

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, odoo

**What I've done:**

I have a module with

```
myfield = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Graduate", domain=[('is_graduated', '=', True)])
```

Then I have another class with

```
_inherit = 'res.partner'
is_graduated = fields.Boolean("Graduated before?", default=False)
graduations = fields.Many2many('my_module.courses', string="Graduation courses")
```

**What I get:**

The `myfield` works good, but the `graduations` field is empty. If you edit `user 1` profile you can add entries to `graduation` field using `Add item`, but I need it to be filled automaticaly.

**What I expect:**

I expect that every record where `myfield` is set to lets say `user 1`, will be visible in field `graduations` when you open `user 1` profile. When I create record and set `myfield` value to lets say `user 1`, that record must to be visible in `user 1` profile in the field `graduations`. How to achieve that?

Comment: And where does the `is_graduated` field come into play? You don't mention it in the "What I expect" section. Also, what the `my_module.courses` model is supposed to represent? It's hard for me to understand what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

user_rel_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='course',
                            relation='user_course_rel',
                            column1='user_id',
                            column2='course_id')

Or

```
user_rel_id = fields.Many2many('course')
```

For Filling Data (for add new relation)

```
user_rel_id = [(4,course_id)]
```

According to http://odoo4u.blogspot.com/2014/10/orm-methods.html, It says:
A full list of options is in the documentation for the class.
This same thing will apply for one2many

> For a **many2many**  and **one2many** field, a list of tuples is
>   expected. Here is the list of the tuple that is accepted, with the
>   corresponding semantics:
>
> `(0, 0,  { values })` link to a **new record** that needs to be
>   created with the given values dictionary
>
> `(1, ID, { values })` **update** the linked record with id = ID (write
>   values on it)
>
> `(2, ID)` remove and **delete** the linked record with id = ID (calls
>   unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to
>   it as well)
>
> `(3, ID)` cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (**delete the
>   relationship** between the two objects but does not delete the target
>   object itself)
>
> `(4, ID)` **link** to existing record with id = ID (adds a
>   relationship)
>
> `(5)` **unlink all** (like using (3, ID) for all linked records)
>
> `(6, 0, [IDs])` **replace** the list of linked IDs (like using (5)
>   then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the object name of the relation table i have just created? i want to use http.request.registry['name_of_relation_table'] to modify the relation table...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `onchange method` for `myfield`, then inside it you need to fill the `graduations` field, something like this:

```
@api.onchange('myfield'):
def _onchange_myfield(self):
    #fill graduations field here...
    ...
```

Comment: But the `graduations` field is in different form at all, so maybe there is any other method to automatically fill the values? Like creating a relation or something?

Comment: like you say: If you edit `user 1` profile you can add entries to `graduation` field using `Add item`, you need to do this operation inside `onchange method` above, and if you need to get access to another model you should use `self.env.['other_model']`, in this case other_model is 'res.partner'. I hope this can be useful for you! Let me know your discharges...

Answer (score 1):

```
_inherit = 'crm.phonecall'    
alarm_ids = fields.Many2many('calendar.alarm',string="Reminders") 
 set the alarm_ids of calendar.event model in create method of crm phonecall...
 alarm_ids = [(6,0,self.alarm_ids.ids)] 

_inherit = 'calendar.event'
 alarm_ids = fields.Many2many('calendar.alarm',string="Reminders")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like these.

For example:

```
@api.one
@api.depends(
      #here you may define your depend field name
)
def _set_graduations(self):
    #here comes your logic which will collect ids
    #and than return it with self.field_name like

    self.graduations = [list_of_ids]


graduations = fields.Many2many('my_module.courses', string='Payments',
                                compute='_set_graduations')
```

If you don't want to use *@api.depends* than you may use *@api.multi*. For reference you may check out *account* module with *account_invoice.py* file.

Comment: And could you help me with logic to collect ids? As I mentioned before, the ids selected should be where `is_graduated` is set to `True`. How could I achieve that?

Comment: you may try with this `self.env['model.name'].search([('field_name', '=', Value)])` now in your case you need to do like `self.env['res.partner'].search([('is_graduated', '=', True)])`

Comment: If I do lets say `self.graduations = self.env['res.partner'].search([('is_graduated', '=', True)])` I get internal error

Comment: may you write that error? and just try to solve it out some part buddy. I just write code in air.

Comment: Compute doesn't work on many2many fields as far as I know. Won't get triggered