# how to display many2many relationship data in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

First Table

```
class vehicle_service(models.Model):                                                        
    s_type=fields.Many2many('service.service','service_rel','sid','s_type',string="Service Name", required="1")
```

Second Table

```
class service_service(models.Model):

    _name="service.service"


    name=fields.Char("Name")
    cost=fields.Float("Service Cost")
```

Comment: how to display in third table using id of service_rel

Comment: first table name is   _name="vehicle.service"

Comment: Please edit the question to complete it. besides the *_name*, could you write a stub of the third class in order to let us understand better what you need to accomplish?

Comment: refer answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853402/filling-many2many-field-odoo-8.