# Create a record into many2many table using Web service API in odoo 8

Tags: many-to-many, odoo-8

I need to create a record in mail_vote table(many2many) with fields message_id and user_id Using Web service API. I found a document here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write . But i don't know how to use that in my code. Any solution please[image].

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853402/filling-many2many-field-odoo-8

Comment: @prakash, i need to create a record into many2many table using Web service API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below i am posting the code snippet for associating `(6,0,[ids])]`  the Many2many record in `product.attribute.line`.

> In Php here i  have used `ripcord` for this task.

```
$existing_prodid = 59;
$existing_attribute_id = 2;
$existing_value_id = 4;
$product_attribute_line = $models->execute($db, $uid, $password,
                                   'product.attribute.line','create',
                                    array('product_tmpl_id' => $existing_prodid;,
                                        'attribute_id'=>$existing_attribute_id,
                                        'value_ids'=>array(array(6,0,array($existing_value_id)))
                                             ))
```

Here the `product.attribute.line`  have have Many2many relation with `product.attribute.value`

So  this is how i associated  a records for  `value_ids` [`'value_ids'=>array(array(6,0,array($existing_value_id)))`].

> In python  i  have used `xmlrpclib` for this task.

```
attibute_line = models.execute_kw(dbname, uid, password,
                   'product.attribute.line', 'create',
                   [{'product_tmpl_id':59,'attribute_id':2,'value_ids':[(6,0,[4])]}] )
```

I hope this may help in your case

Comment: here is my requirement. need to 'like' messages in messaging module using web service API.
messages are stored in 'mail.messages' , relation keeps in  'mail.vote'.

Comment: i tried with this: execute(dbname, uid, pwd,'mail.message', 'write',[475],{'vote_user_ids':[(0,0,[6])]}). but getting error list object has no attribute get.

Comment: [(0,0,{})]  is used for adding a record in the model  and [(1,id,{})] for updating the record values  for the specif id , you will have to pass the dictionary in both the cases, {'vote_user_ids':[(0,0,[6])]} is not the valid syntax , please read  link care fully :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853402/filling-many2many-field-odoo-8

Comment: i tried this 
.execute(dbname, uid, pwd,'mail.message', 'write',[475],{'vote_user_ids':[(4,6)]}) Now getting an error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: Users - res.users]: ''&gt;

Comment: i am using xmlrpc/2  here is the code for it  models.execute_kw(dbname, uid, password,    'mail.message', 'write',[[475],{ 'vote_user_ids':[(4,6)]}]  )

Comment: i tried this: execute(dbname, uid, pwd,'mail.message', 'write',[498],{'vote_user_ids':[(4,uid)]}), its successfully run and returned TRUE, but no records created in 'mail.vote' (the relation table) ?????????

Comment: when i am trying this: sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd,'mail.message', 'write',[[511],{'vote_user_ids':[(4,uid)]}]), got this error = Fault: &lt;Fault unhashable type: 'list': 'Traceback