# Set the tax_id for a sales order with PHP api in Odoo

Tags: php, odoo

I'm having a strange amount of trouble setting `tax_id` on Odoo `sale.order.line` models. My inital code is somewhat like this:

```
$sale_order_line = $models->execute_kw($info['database'], $info['uid'], $info['password'], 'sale.order.line', 'create', array(
  array(
    'name' => $product['name'],
    'order_id' => (int) $sale_order,
    'product_id' => (int) $product['id'],
    'product_uom' => 1,
    'product_uom_qty' => (float) $line_item->quantity->value(),
    'price_unit' => $product['list_price'],
    'tax_id' => array(13),
  )
));
```

The id of 13 definitely exists and has been set on order line items created in the front end. I've tried passing it in as a single integer, string, array of integers, array of strings, array of arrays of integers, etc etc, but still no tax_id is set when retrieving the model back again.

I even tried doing a `create` with no tax and then doing a `write` afterwards to set the tax, because I thought perhaps with a `many2many` relationship, that would be the only way to get it to recognise the connection between them, but that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't issue a bounty for another two days, so if anyone can help me in the next few hours, I will draw you a delightful picture of your choosing. C'mon, you can't deny that incentive, can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `tax_id` is the **Many2many** field , so  use can not  pass the direct array of id in to it.

use this syntax  `'tax_id'=>array(array(6,0,array(13)))`

For more info visit my answer here  [create-a-record-into-many2many-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643092/create-a-record-into-many2many-table-using-web-service-api-in-odoo-8/36709180#36709180)

I Hope it may solved  your issue .

Comment: Ah Prakash, you legend! It works, thanks. What's with the `6,0,[ids]` syntax then? What do those numbers represent? I saw something elsewhere that had mentioned those values but I had assumed it was something deprecated or not related to Ripcord/PHP. Thank you again.

Comment: Well you'll have to decide what you want the drawing of first! :P

Comment: You made my day :)