# Invoice number and taxes amounts creating invoices from custom Odoo module

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I'm migrating invoices from `OpenERP` 7 database to Odoo8. I'm retrieving OERP7 data with psycopg2 and then using `envs` and model.create() to insert invoices into Odoo8 database. In general, the code works fine, but `Odoo8` is not generating the invoice number (associated to account_move table) and `amount_tax`.

My codes are the following:

**Import Account Invoice**

```
class ImportAccountInvoice(Command):
    """Import account invoices from source DB"""

    def process_account_invoice(self, model, data):
        if not data:
            return

        # Model structure
        model.create({
            'account_id': data['account_id'],
            'amount_tax': data['amount_tax'],
            'amount_total': data['amount_total'],
            'amount_untaxed': data['amount_untaxed'],
            'check_total': data['check_total'],
            'company_id': data['company_id'],
            'currency_id': data['currency_id'],
            'date_due': data['date_due'],
            'date_invoice': data['date_invoice'],
            'fiscal_position': data['fiscal_position'],
            'internal_number': data['internal_number'],
            'move_name': data['move_name'],
            'name': data['name'],
            'origin': data['origin'],
            'partner_id': data['partner_id'],
            'period_id': data['period_id'],
            'reconciled': data['reconciled'],
            'reference': data['reference'],
            'residual': data['residual'],
            'state': data['state'],
            'type': data['type'],
            'ship_addr_city': data['ship_addr_city'],
            'ship_addr_name': data['ship_addr_name'],
            'client_notes': data['client_notes'],
            'ship_addr_state': data['ship_addr_state'],
            'ship_addr_street': data['ship_addr_street'],
            'ship_addr_phone': data['ship_addr_phone'],
            'ship_addr_zip': data['ship_addr_zip'],
            'drupal_order_name': data['drupal_order_name'],
            'payment_method': data['payment_method'],
            'drupal_total': data['drupal_total']
        })


    def run(self, cmdargs):
        print "Importing account invoices"
        execute_old_database_query("""
            SELECT i.id, i.account_id, i.amount_tax, i.amount_total, i.amount_untaxed, i.check_total, i.company_id, i.currency_id, i.date_due, 
                    i.date_invoice, i.fiscal_position, i.internal_number, i.journal_id, i.move_name, i.name, i.origin, i.partner_id, i.period_id, 
                    i.reconciled, i.reference, i.residual, i.sent, i.state, i.type, i.x_dir_city, i.x_dir_name, i.x_dir_observations, 
                    i.x_dir_state, i.x_dir_street, i.x_dir_telephone, i.x_dir_zip, i.x_drupal_order, i.x_pago, i.x_total,
                    rp.id, rp.email, rp.name, rp.type, rp.vat, rp.street,
                    rc.id, rc.name,
                    aa.id, aa.code, aa.name,
                    ap.id, ap.code, ap.name, ap.date_start, ap.date_stop,
                    aj.type, aj.code,
                    fp.name
                FROM account_invoice i
                    LEFT JOIN res_partner rp
                        ON rp.id = i.partner_id
                    LEFT JOIN res_currency rc
                        ON rc.id = i.currency_id
                    LEFT JOIN account_account aa
                        ON aa.id = i.account_id
                    LEFT JOIN account_period ap
                        ON ap.id = i.partner_id
                    LEFT JOIN account_journal aj
                        ON aj.id = i.journal_id
                    LEFT JOIN account_fiscal_position fp
                        ON fp.id = i.fiscal_position
                ORDER BY i.id;
        """)

        openerp.tools.config.parse_config(cmdargs)
        dbname = openerp.tools.config['db_name']
        r = modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(dbname)
        cr = r.cursor()

        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(cr, 1, {})
            # Define target model 
            account_invoice = env['account.invoice']

            id_ptr = None
            c_data = {}
            while True:
                r = src_cr.fetchone()
                if not r:
                    self.process_account_invoice(account_invoice, c_data)
                    break

                print r

                account = env['account.account'].search([('code','=',r[43]),('name','=',r[44]),])
                currency = env['res.currency'].search([('name','=',r[41]),])

                period = match_account_period(env,code=r[46],name=r[47],date_start=r[48],date_stop=r[49])
                journal = match_account_journal(env,type=r[50],code=r[51])
                fiscal_position = match_account_fiscal_position(env,name=r[52])

                company_id = 1
                if r[38] is not None and r[39] is not None:
                    partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[35]),('name','=',r[36]),('type','=',r[37]),('vat','=',r[38]),('street','=',r[39])])
                elif r[38] is not None:
                    partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[35]),('name','=',r[36]),('type','=',r[37]),('vat','=',r[38])])
                elif r[39] is not None:
                    partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[35]),('name','=',r[36]),('type','=',r[37]),('street','=',r[39])])
                else:
                    partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[35]),('name','=',r[36]),('type','=',r[37])])

                # Take one when partners are duplicated
                partner_id = partner.id if len(list(partner)) <= 1 else partner[0].id
                fiscal_position_id = fiscal_position.id if fiscal_position else None

                if id_ptr != r[0]:
                    self.process_account_invoice(account_invoice, c_data)
                    id_ptr = r[0]

                    c_data = {
                        'id': r[0],
                        'account_id': account.id,
                        'amount_tax': r[2],
                        'amount_total': r[3],
                        'amount_untaxed': r[4],
                        'check_total': r[5],
                        'company_id': company_id,
                        'currency_id': currency.id,
                        'date_due': r[8],
                        'date_invoice': r[9],
                        'fiscal_position': fiscal_position_id,
                        'internal_number': r[11],
                        'journal_id': journal.id,
                        'move_name': r[13],
                        'name': r[14],
                        'origin': r[15],
                        'partner_id': partner_id,
                        'partner_invoice_id': partner_id,
                        'partner_shipping_id': partner_id,
                        'period_id': period.id,
                        'reconciled': r[18],
                        'reference': r[19],
                        'residual': r[20],
                        'sent': r[21],
                        'state': r[22],
                        'type': r[23],
                        'ship_addr_city': r[24],
                        'ship_addr_name': r[25],
                        'client_notes': r[26],
                        'ship_addr_state': r[27],
                        'ship_addr_country': '',
                        'ship_addr_street': r[28],
                        'ship_addr_phone': r[29],
                        'ship_addr_zip': r[30],
                        'drupal_order_name': r[31],
                        'payment_method': r[32],
                        'drupal_total': r[33]
                    }

        cr.commit()
        cr.close()
```

**Import Account Invoice Lines**

```
class ImportAccountInvoiceLine(Command):
    """Import account invoice lines from source DB"""

    def process_account_invoice_line(self, model, data):
        if not data:
            return

        # Model structure
        m = {
            'account_id': data['account_id'],
            'create_date': data['create_date'],
            'company_id': data['company_id'],
            'discount': data['discount'],
            'invoice_id': data['invoice_id'],
            'name': data['name'],
            'partner_id': data['partner_id'],
            'product_id': data['product_id'],
            'quantity': data['quantity'],
            'price_unit': data['price_unit'],
            'price_subtotal': data['price_subtotal'],
            'supplier_name': data['supplier_name'],
            'supplier_ref': data['supplier_ref'],
            'item_lot_number': data['item_lot_number'],
            'item_expiration': data['item_expiration'],
            'item_delivery_note': data['item_delivery_note'],
        }

        if not data['invoice_line_tax_id'] is None:
            m['invoice_line_tax_id'] = [(4,data['invoice_line_tax_id'])] # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853402/filling-many2many-field-odoo-8

        print model.create(m)


    def recalculate_tax_amount(self,cr):
        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(cr, 1, {})
            invoices = env['account.invoice'].search([])
            account_invoice_tax = env['account.invoice.tax']
            print "Recalculating invoice taxes"
            for invoice in invoices:
                print invoice
                print invoice.action_move_create()
#                print invoice.button_reset_taxes()

                if invoice.id <= 32600:
                    break

    def run(self, cmdargs):
        print "Importing account invoice lines"
        execute_old_database_query("""
            SELECT il.id, il.account_id, il.create_date, il.company_id, il.discount, il.invoice_id, il.name, il.partner_id, il.price_unit, 
                    il.price_subtotal, il.product_id, il.quantity, il.x_prov, il.x_ref_prov, il.x_lote, il.x_caducidad, il.x_albaran,
                    i.internal_number, i.name, i.origin, i.reference, i.type, i.x_drupal_order, i.date_invoice,
                    rp.email, rp.name, rp.type, rp.vat, rp.street,
                    pp.default_code, pp.name_template, pp.x_subcategoria, pp.x_marca,
                    at.type_tax_use, at.name
                FROM account_invoice_line il
                    LEFT JOIN account_invoice i
                        ON i.id = il.invoice_id
                    LEFT JOIN res_partner rp
                        ON rp.id = il.partner_id
                    LEFT JOIN product_product pp
                        ON pp.id = il.product_id
                    LEFT JOIN account_invoice_line_tax ailt
                        ON ailt.invoice_line_id = il.id
                    LEFT JOIN account_tax at
                        ON at.id = ailt.tax_id
                WHERE il.id > 28700
                ORDER BY il.id DESC;
        """)

        openerp.tools.config.parse_config(cmdargs)
        dbname = openerp.tools.config['db_name']
        r = modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(dbname)
        cr = r.cursor()

        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(cr, 1, {})
            # Define target model 
            account_invoice_line = env['account.invoice.line']

            id_ptr = None
            c_data = {}

            company_id = 1
            while True:
                r = src_cr.fetchone()
                if not r:
                    self.process_account_invoice_line(account_invoice_line, c_data)
                    break

                print r

                print r[17],r[18],r[19],r[20],r[21]

                if not (r[17] is None and r[18] is None and r[19] is None and r[20] is None):
                    account_invoice = env['account.invoice'].search([('internal_number','=',r[17]),('name','=',r[18]),('origin','=',r[19]),('reference','=',r[20]),('type','=',r[21]),('drupal_order_name','=',r[22]),('date_invoice','=',r[23])])
                    print "normal"
                else:
                    print "parner"
                    if r[27] is not None and r[28] is not None:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26]),('vat','=',r[27]),('street','=',r[28])])
                    elif r[27] is not None:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26]),('vat','=',r[27])])
                    elif r[28] is not None:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26]),('street','=',r[28])])
                    else:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26])])

                    # Take one when partners are duplicated
                    partner_id = partner.id if len(list(partner)) <= 1 else partner[0].id
                    account_invoice = env['account.invoice'].search([('internal_number','=',r[17]),('name','=',r[18]),('origin','=',r[19]),('reference','=',r[20]),('type','=',r[21]),('drupal_order_name','=',r[22]),('date_invoice','=',r[23]),('partner_id','=',partner_id)])

                    if not account_invoice: # If there is not an account_invoice for this partner, continue with the next row
                        print "^ NO INVOICE FOR THIS LINE ^"
                        continue 

                product = env['product.product'].search([('default_code','=',r[29]),('name_template','=',r[30]),('subcategory_txt','=',r[31]),('brand','=',r[32])])

                # Take one when invoices are duplicated
                invoice = account_invoice if len(list(account_invoice)) <= 1 else account_invoice[0]
                # Take one when products are duplicated
                product_id = product.id if len(list(product)) <= 1 else product[0].id

                print r[33],r[34]
                if r[33] is None and r[34] is None:
                    tax_id = None
                else:
                    tax = match_account_tax(env, r[33], r[34])
                    tax_id = tax.id

                if id_ptr != r[0]:
                    self.process_account_invoice_line(account_invoice_line, c_data)
                    id_ptr = r[0]

                    c_data = {
                        'id': r[0],
                        'account_id': invoice.account_id.id,
                        'create_date': r[2],
                        'company_id': r[3],
                        'discount': r[4],
                        'invoice_id': invoice.id,
                        'name': r[6],
                        'partner_id': invoice.partner_id.id,
                        'price_unit': r[8],
                        'price_subtotal': r[9],
                        'product_id': product_id,
                        'quantity': r[11],
                        'supplier_name': r[12],
                        'supplier_ref': r[13],
                        'item_lot_number': r[14],
                        'item_expiration': r[15],
                        'item_delivery_note': r[16],
                        'invoice_line_tax_id': tax_id
                    }

        cr.commit()

        self.recalculate_tax_amount(cr)

        cr.close()
```

I have associated Journals, Periods... but I can't get `Odoo` creates the account.move and compute all taxes. What should I do?

**IMPORTANT**: I need to assign the same number each invoice already have in old database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a function to update invoice taxes and move, at the end of invoice lines insertion and before commit.

The function:

```
def refresh_invoices_and_recompute_taxes(self, model, invoice_ids):
    for i in invoice_ids:
        print "Updating invoice", i
        invoice = model.browse(i)
        print "- Computing taxes"
        invoice.button_compute(set_total=True)
        invoice.action_date_assign()
        print "- Creating account move"
        invoice.action_move_create()
        print "- Assigning number"
        invoice.action_number()
```

My class:

```
class ImportAccountInvoiceLine(Command):
    """Import account invoice lines from source DB"""

    def process_account_invoice_line(self, model, data):
        if not data:
            return

        m = {
            'account_id': data['account_id'],
            'create_date': data['create_date'],
            'company_id': data['company_id'],
            'discount': data['discount'],
            'invoice_id': data['invoice_id'],
            'name': data['name'],
            'partner_id': data['partner_id'],
            'product_id': data['product_id'],
            'quantity': data['quantity'],
            'price_unit': data['price_unit'],
            'price_subtotal': data['price_subtotal'],
            'supplier_name': data['supplier_name'],
            'supplier_ref': data['supplier_ref'],
            'item_lot_number': data['item_lot_number'],
            'item_expiration': data['item_expiration'],
            'item_delivery_note': data['item_delivery_note'],
        }

        if not data['invoice_line_tax_id'] is None:
            m['invoice_line_tax_id'] = [(4,data['invoice_line_tax_id'])] # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853402/filling-many2many-field-odoo-8

        # Model structure
        model.create(m)

    def refresh_invoices_and_recompute_taxes(self, model,invoice_ids):
        for i in invoice_ids:
            print "Updating invoice", i
            invoice = model.browse(i)
            print "- Computing taxes"
            invoice.button_compute(set_total=True)
            invoice.action_date_assign()
            print "- Creating account move"
            invoice.action_move_create()
            print "- Assigning number"
            invoice.action_number()


    def run(self, cmdargs):
        print "Importing account invoice lines"
        execute_old_database_query("""
            SELECT il.id, il.account_id, il.create_date, il.company_id, il.discount, il.invoice_id, il.name, il.partner_id, il.price_unit, 
                    il.price_subtotal, il.product_id, il.quantity, il.x_prov, il.x_ref_prov, il.x_lote, il.x_caducidad, il.x_albaran,
                    i.internal_number, i.name, i.origin, i.reference, i.type, i.x_drupal_order, i.date_invoice,
                    rp.email, rp.name, rp.type, rp.vat, rp.street,
                    pp.default_code, pp.name_template, pp.x_subcategoria, pp.x_marca,
                    at.type_tax_use, at.name
                FROM account_invoice_line il
                    LEFT JOIN account_invoice i
                        ON i.id = il.invoice_id
                    LEFT JOIN res_partner rp
                        ON rp.id = il.partner_id
                    LEFT JOIN product_product pp
                        ON pp.id = il.product_id
                    LEFT JOIN account_invoice_line_tax ailt
                        ON ailt.invoice_line_id = il.id
                    LEFT JOIN account_tax at
                        ON at.id = ailt.tax_id
                ORDER BY il.invoice_id ASC, il.id ASC
                LIMIT 10000;
        """)

        openerp.tools.config.parse_config(cmdargs)
        dbname = openerp.tools.config['db_name']
        r = modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(dbname)
        cr = r.cursor()

        invoice_ids = []
        inv_id = 0
        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(cr, 1, {})
            # Define target model 
            account_invoice_line = env['account.invoice.line']

            id_ptr = None
            c_data = {}

            company_id = 1
            while True:
                r = src_cr.fetchone()
                if not r:
                    self.process_account_invoice_line(account_invoice_line, c_data)
                    break

                if not (r[17] is None and r[18] is None and r[19] is None and r[20] is None):
                    account_invoice = env['account.invoice'].search([('internal_number','=',r[17]),('name','=',r[18]),('origin','=',r[19]),('reference','=',r[20]),('type','=',r[21]),('drupal_order_name','=',r[22]),('date_invoice','=',r[23])])
                else:
                    if r[27] is not None and r[28] is not None:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26]),('vat','=',r[27]),('street','=',r[28])])
                    elif r[27] is not None:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26]),('vat','=',r[27])])
                    elif r[28] is not None:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26]),('street','=',r[28])])
                    else:
                        partner = env['res.partner'].search([('email','=',r[24]),('name','=',r[25]),('type','=',r[26])])

                    # Take one when partners are duplicated
                    partner_id = partner.id if len(list(partner)) <= 1 else partner[0].id
                    account_invoice = env['account.invoice'].search([('internal_number','=',r[17]),('name','=',r[18]),('origin','=',r[19]),('reference','=',r[20]),('type','=',r[21]),('drupal_order_name','=',r[22]),('date_invoice','=',r[23]),('partner_id','=',partner_id)])

                    if not account_invoice: # If there is not an account_invoice for this partner, continue with the next row
                        print "^ NO INVOICE FOR THIS LINE ^"
                        continue 

                product = env['product.product'].search([('default_code','=',r[29]),('name_template','=',r[30]),('subcategory_txt','=',r[31]),('brand','=',r[32])])

                # Take one when invoices are duplicated
                invoice = account_invoice if len(list(account_invoice)) <= 1 else account_invoice[0]
                # Take one when products are duplicated
                product_id = product.id if len(list(product)) <= 1 else product[0].id
                if not invoice:
                    continue
                else:
                    if inv_id != invoice.id:
                        inv_id = invoice.id
                        invoice_ids.append(inv_id)

                tax = match_account_tax(env, r[33], r[34])
                tax_id = tax.id if tax is not None and tax else None

                if id_ptr != r[0]:
                    id_ptr = r[0]

                    c_data = {
                        'id': r[0],
                        'account_id': invoice.account_id.id,
                        'create_date': r[2],
                        'company_id': r[3],
                        'discount': r[4],
                        'invoice_id': invoice.id,
                        'name': r[6],
                        'partner_id': invoice.partner_id.id,
                        'price_unit': r[8],
                        'price_subtotal': r[9],
                        'product_id': product_id,
                        'quantity': r[11],
                        'supplier_name': r[12],
                        'supplier_ref': r[13],
                        'item_lot_number': r[14],
                        'item_expiration': r[15],
                        'item_delivery_note': r[16],
                        'invoice_line_tax_id': tax_id
                    }

                    self.process_account_invoice_line(account_invoice_line, c_data)

            self.refresh_invoices_and_recompute_taxes(env['account.invoice'], invoice_ids)

        cr.commit()
        cr.close()
```