# I am trying to inherit and add one2many fields in res.partner model . It shows errror : Invalid field 'same_vat_partner_id' on model 'vehicle.brand'

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

inherited " res.partner " and added a page (editable tree) in notebook section, but when clicking on "Add a line" it is showing below error:

```
Invalid field 'same_vat_partner_id' on model 'vehicle.brand'
```

My code to inherit res.partner and add One2many fields in it :

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class CustomContacts(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.partner"


x_brand_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner.line', 'x_brand_id', string="Brand Name")
x_model_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_model_id', string="Model Name")


class CustomContactsPage(models.Model):
_name = "res.partner.line"

x_brand_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.brand', string="Brand Name")
x_model_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.model', string="Model Name")
```

My code of vehicle.brand model :

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class BrandCreate(models.Model):
_name = "vehicle.brand"
_description = "Customer"

name = fields.Char(string='Brand Name', required=True)
```

My code of vehicle.model model :

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class ModelName(models.Model):
_name = "vehicle.model"
_description = "Models"


name = fields.Char(string='Model Name', required=True)
```

My code of view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<record id="view_partner_form_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='internal_notes']" position="after">
            <page string="Vehicle Details">
                    <field name="x_brand_ids"></field>
                    <field name="x_model_ids"></field>
            </page>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Getting view inside view as mentioned in below images :

[view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irHuO.png)

[view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IltMY.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You needs to understand the Many2many and One2many fields.
For many2many you check the required argument is the model name only. and other are optional. ([Filling Many2many field (odoo 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853402/filling-many2many-field-odoo-8))

```
x_brand_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner.line', string="Brand Name")
```

For adding One2many we need many2one with that same model.

```
x_model_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_model_id', string="Model Name")
```

For this you need x_model_id Many2one of res.partner field under res.partner.line

You need to like below:

```
class CustomContacts(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.partner"


x_brand_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner.line', string="Brand Name")
x_model_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'x_model_id', string="Model Name")


class CustomContactsPage(models.Model):
_name = "res.partner.line"

x_brand_id = fields.Many2one('vehicle.brand', string="Brand Name")
x_model_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Model Name")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering it worked but why i am getting view inside view ?? I have edited the question and added 2 images which is the view i am getting.

Answer (score 1):

When using a [One2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.One2many) field the `inverse_name` (**x_model_id** in your example) is equal to the current record and Odoo tries to recompute the partner vat using `vehicle.model` record in place of a `res.partner` record and this is why you are getting that error.

To fix it just define the inverse name in `vehicle.brand` model and use it in `x_model_ids` field instead of `x_model_id`.

***Example:***

```
class CustomContacts(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    x_model_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner.line', 'model_id', string="Model Name")


class CustomContactsPage(models.Model):
    _name = "res.partner.line"

    model_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
```

**Edit:**

If you want to edit the `One2many` field in place, define it inside the form view like following:

```
<field name="x_model_ids">
    <tree editable="bottom">

    </tree>
</field>
```

For the `Many2many` fields, Odoo will open a dialog to select or create vehicle brands.

Comment: Thanks for answer but do i need to add res.partner as comodel name in model_id. I think there i need to add vehicle.model to fetch its data. ??

Comment: The comodel should be `res.partner` in my example above and if you need to link `res.partner.line` to `vehicle.model` keep the `x_model_id` field. My example shows only how to add a one2many field in the res partner model that let you add partner lines (`res.partner.line`).

Comment: This is how Odoo is designed, when you use a one2many field in model `A` with  comodel `B`, you should add the inverse relation (a Many2one field) in model `B` that references model A and use it as the `inverse_name`.

Comment: Define a tree view for `vehicle.brand` and `vehicle.vehicle` models and Odoo will automatically use them as subviews.